# How do I export this named function through module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, discord.js

I have a command file for a discord bot that contains the command and a piece of parsing logic contained within a function that I want to reuse within my `index.js`

```js
// file: ./commands/scrumPrompt.js

// The function

const extractDeets = function (f, scrum) {
  let items = [];
  let re = new RegExp("(\n[ -]*" + f + ".*)", "g");
  let replace = new RegExp("[ -]*" + f + "[ ]+");
  for (const item of scrum.matchAll(re)) {
    items.push(item[1].trim().replace(replace, ""));
  }

  return items;
};


// The actual command itself within the same file
module.exports = {
  name: "scrum",
  usage: `!scrum < followed by your message >  as per Standup format - refer !show for showing the format`,
  description: "Reply to standup prompt",
  async execute(message, args) {
    if (message.channel.type === "text") {
      if (!args.length)
        return message.reply(
          "Please Provide your scrum as per the format in help menu !scrum < your message >"
        );
      else {
        if (message.author.id !== -1) {
          const client = new MongoClient(MONGO_URI);

          try {
            const database = client.db(DB_NAME);
            const members = database.collection("members");

            const query = { user_id: message.author.id };
            const membersdetail = await members.findOne(query);

            if (membersdetail !== null) {
              // since this method returns the matched document, not a cursor, print it directly
              //console.log("Adding Scrum for ", membersdetail.email);

              let userscrum = args.splice(0).join(" ");

              // Check if multiple !scrum commands are present in developer scrum message
              if (userscrum.includes("!scrum") == false) {
                // Expects notations of "-" to exist
                let [f, e, b, o, bl] = ["f", "e", "b", "o", "x"];

                let features = extractDeets(f, userscrum);
                let enhancements = extractDeets(e, userscrum);
                let bugs = extractDeets(b, userscrum);
                let others = extractDeets(o, userscrum);
                let blockers = extractDeets(bl, userscrum);
    .
    .
    .
};
```

I want to keep the name of the function as `extractDeets()` itself so that it doesn't mess with the usage within the command as well. I'm not completely sure how to export it into the `index.js` because it's already kind of being imported here:

```js
// Imports the command file + adds the command to the bot commands collection
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

I'm unsure of how to add the function as another import, maybe I should export it into another file and then import it from there? I'm not sure if that's possible or doable here. I've tried directly importing from here but then the command doesn't work, which is troublesome.

Comment: Include is as an optional key in your exported object: `module.exports = { ..., extractDeets }` to then access it through `command?.extractDeets()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
module.exports = { extractDeets };
```

Later, you can import it like this:

```js
const { extractDeets } = require('../your_file');
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but it results in the command not working, as I said. Maybe it's because there are two import statements? That or I'm calling the function wrong? It should still be `extractDeets()`.